# Initialize multipleoutputs instance in configure method in MapReduceBase

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In my Reduce class i need multiple outputs... Im using MapReduceBase. How to initialize my multipleoutputs instance(i.e out) in my configure method? Since i am not able to initialize im getting null pointer exception... Please help me... here is my code

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
        Reducer<Text, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
    private MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text> out;

    public void configure(JobConf job) {

    }
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
            OutputCollector<NullWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            try {
                out.write(NullWritable.get(), values.next(), "outoutPath/"
                        + key.toString());//Null pointer exception
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your map class? You have to write mapper class such that it should put key value pairs. When your reducer gets call it will fetch data based on the keys you have put in your mapper

Answer (score 0):

Here is an right example.

```
public class ReducerToFileSystem extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
{
private MultipleOutputs<Text, Text> mos;

public void setup(Context context){
    mos = new MultipleOutputs<Text, Text>(context);
}

//public void reduce(Text key, Text value, Context context) 
//throws IOException, InterruptedException (This was the mistake, changed the signature and it worked fine)
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    //context.write(key, value);
    mos.write("cdb1", key, value, OUTPUT_DIR+"/"+"cdb1");
    mos.write("cdb2", key, value, OUTPUT_DIR+"/"+"cdb2");
    context.progress();
}

public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException         {
    mos.close();
}
}
```